# Setting Multiple alarms on my alarm application

Tags: android, alarm

In my application I am able to play alarm tone on specified time using timepicker..But when i press the set alarm button again it replaces the previous alarm.. Could anyone help to store multiple alarms...and also please tell where the time for ringing the alarm is stored in application?

Alarmreceiver.java

```
    package com.example.alaram;

import java.io.IOException;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.media.AudioManager;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.media.RingtoneManager;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.PowerManager;
import android.os.PowerManager.WakeLock;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Window;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.widget.Button;




            public class AlarmReceiver extends Activity{
        private MediaPlayer mPlayer;
        private WakeLock mWakeLock;
            Button stopalarm;

        @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    PowerManager pm=(PowerManager) getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
    mWakeLock =pm.newWakeLock(PowerManager.FULL_WAKE_LOCK, "my wakelock");
    mWakeLock.acquire();
    this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    this.getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN | 
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED | 
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TURN_SCREEN_ON, 
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN |
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED | 
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TURN_SCREEN_ON );

    setContentView(R.layout.alarmreceiver);

    //Stop the alarm music
    stopalarm=(Button) findViewById(R.id.btnStopoAlarm);
    stopalarm.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
             mPlayer.stop();
                finish();
                return;
        }
    });
    PlaySound(this,getAlarmUri());
}


private void PlaySound(Context context,Uri alert){
    mPlayer=new MediaPlayer();
    try{
        mPlayer.setDataSource(context,alert);
        final AudioManager am=(AudioManager) getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
        if(am.getStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_ALARM)!=0);
        {
            mPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_ALARM);
            mPlayer.prepare();
            mPlayer.start();
        }

    }catch(IOException e)
    {
    Log.i("AlaramReciever", "no audio file");
    }
}

 //Get an alarm sound.  If none set, try notification, Otherwise, ringtone.
private Uri getAlarmUri()
{
    Uri alert= RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
    if(alert==null)
    {
        alert= RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
        if(alert==null)
        {
            alert=RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_RINGTONE);
        }
    }
    return alert;
}

protected void onStop(){
    super.onStop();
     mWakeLock.release();

}
```

}

SetAlarm.java

```
package com.example.alaram;

import java.util.Calendar;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlarmManager;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TimePicker;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class SetAlarm extends Activity {

TimePicker timePicker;
Button ok;
int hrs,min;
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.setalarm);

//Operation of Ok button or Setting Alaram Time
ok=(Button) findViewById(R.id.btnOk);
ok.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        Intent intent=new Intent(SetAlarm.this,AlarmReceiver.class);
        PendingIntent pi=PendingIntent.getActivity(SetAlarm.this, 2,    intent,PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
        AlarmManager alm=(AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);

        timePicker=(TimePicker) findViewById(R.id.timePicker1);
        hrs=timePicker.getCurrentHour();
        min=timePicker.getCurrentMinute();
        Calendar calendar=Calendar.getInstance();
        calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY,hrs);
        calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, min);
        calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);

        alm.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,calendar.getTimeInMillis(), pi);
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Alaram is Set",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        finish();   
        }

    });

}
```

}

Answer (score 3):

This is because you always use the same Intent. If you want to have more than one alarm scheduled, you need to modify your intent. For instance you can define an integer `id` and increase it for every new alarm by one. Then you can use the code below to assign this `id` to the `intent`.

```
public class AlarmReceiver extends Activity {

    private int id = 0;

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        Intent intent=new Intent(SetAlarm.this,AlarmReceiver.class);
        intent.setData(Uri.parse("alarm:" + (id++)));

        ... rest of your code here
    }

}
```

If you want to `cancel()` alarm, you need to use `intent` with exactly this `id`.

Comment: I am new at java . Can you please tell how to increase id for every alarm?

Comment: Add `private int id = 0;` field to your class and add `intent.setData()` as shown in the answer.

Comment: Still it's replacing the alarm :/

Comment: Thanx all for replying. If i use the original code that i have posted and i want to remove the alarmtone from going off before it starts playing .. How can i do that?

Answer (score 1):

You are settings the same PendingIntent for both alarms [according to documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html#set%28int,%20long,%20android.app.PendingIntent%29) it will be replaced:

> If there is already an alarm for this Intent scheduled (with the
>   equality of two intents being defined by filterEquals(Intent)), then
>   it will be removed and replaced by this one.

[According to the documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#filterEquals%28android.content.Intent%29) two intents are equals base on `filterEquals(Intent)` which mean:

> Determine if two intents are the same for the purposes of intent
>   resolution (filtering). That is, if their action, data, type, class,
>   and categories are the same. This does not compare any extra data
>   included in the intents.

So basically if you want to schedule two alarms just make sure that your Intents are distinct.

Answer (score 0):

you can use `setRepeating` like this

```
alm.setRepeating(type, triggerAtMillis, intervalMillis, operation);
```

Comment: I think you misunderstood me.. I dont want to repeat the alarm in certain duration. I just want to store every alarm that has been set without being replaced